# Powershell giving op_Addition error in for() statement

Tags: powershell

Our PowerShell script is giving an error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named op_Addition'

I am programming a "Four-in-a-row" game, so it has to check if the game contains a four-in-a-row.

This is a piece of my code that checks for a winner:

```
[script]
function winner{

        $spelbordd = @()
        $spelbordd += ,@($A10,$B10,$C10,$D10,$E10,$F10,$G10,$H10,$I10,$J10)  
        $spelbordd += ,@($A9,$B9,$C9,$D9,$E9,$F9,$G9,$H9,$I9,$J9) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A8,$B8,$C8,$D8,$E8,$F8,$G8,$H8,$I8,$J8) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A7,$B7,$C7,$D7,$E7,$F7,$G7,$H7,$I7,$J7) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A6,$B6,$C6,$D6,$E6,$F6,$G6,$H6,$I6,$J6) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A5,$B5,$C5,$D5,$E5,$F5,$G5,$H5,$I5,$J5) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A4,$B4,$C4,$D4,$E4,$F4,$G4,$H4,$I4,$J4) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A3,$B3,$C3,$D3,$E3,$F3,$G3,$H3,$I3,$J3) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A2,$B2,$C2,$D2,$E2,$F2,$G2,$H2,$I2,$J2) 
        $spelbordd += ,@($A1,$B1,$C1,$D1,$E1,$F1,$G1,$H1,$I1,$J1)

        for([int]$i=0; $i -lt 9; $i++){
    if($i -le 5){
        for([int]$r=0; $r -lt 9; $r++){
            if($spelbordd[$i, $r] -and $spelbordd[$i+1, $r] -and $spelbordd[$i+2,$r] -and $spelbordd[$i+3]){
                $winner = $player
             }
         }
    }
    for([int]$r=0; $r -le 5; $r++){
        for([int]$j=0; $j -lt 9; $j++){
            if($spelbordd[$r,$j] -and $spelbordd[$r+1,$j] -and $spelbordd[$r+2,$j] -and $spelbordd[$r+3,$k]){
                $winner = $player
             }
         }
     }
}

$winner
```

What is wrong? I have spent hours of searching on Google, but I can not find a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how to access the elements of your 2-dimenstional array. When you say:

```
$spelbordd[$i, $r]
```

you are saying, give me the elements at $i and at $r, which returns 2 arrays (the 2nd dimension). To access the element at row $i and column $r use:

```
$spelbordd[$i][$r]
```

Comment: It is giving an error like: "index operation failed the array index evaluated to null"

Comment: @user1981919  You've got an undefined $k in there: `$spelbordd[$r+3,$k]` that's probably what's evaluating to null.

Answer (score -1):

While the initial answers 'solved' the OPs problem, they did not answer the question. There was no explanation of why the error message was

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named op_Addition

The answer lies in the somewhat obscure operator precedence in Powershell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence). In particular, ',' (array element separator) has higher precedence than '+' (addition). Thus, while it might be assumed that the array access expression

$spelbordd[$i+1, $r]

returns an array of the two arrays $spelbordd[$i+1] and $spelbordd[$r] (a concatenation of slices), in fact the array element expression [$i+1,$r] parses as [$i+(1,$r)] and so tries to add $i to the array [System.Object[]] (1,$r) by use of its op_Addition method (what happens when you use the '+' operator with a non-ValueType object). Since [System.Object[]] has no op_Addition method, the listed error results.

P.S. In this case, the unexpected precedence problem was only exposed due to a syntactic error (incorrect method to access two dimensional array). However, the subtle operator precedence can manifest in more common expressions. Besides those expressions which create arrays with elements that are themselves expressions, the most likely trap is the format operator '-f' which has precedence between ',' and the arithmetic operators. Thus the following examples produce somewhat unexpected results:

'{0} {1}' -f 1+2, 2
Error, insufficient parameters to format
because it parsed as 
('{0} {1}' -f 1)+(2,2)
and the format failed before attempting to apply '+' to (2,2).

'{0} {1}' -f 1,2+2
1 22
because it parsed as
('{0} {1}' -f (1,2))+2
and the result of ('{0} {1}' -f (1,2)) is a [System.String] which, though it also does not have an op_Addition, has well defined behaviour with the '+' operator in Powershell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators).

'{0} {0}' -f 1+2,2 #use first format parameter twice
1 12 2
because it parsed as
('{0} {0}' -f 1)+(2,2)
and, since the type of the left operand determines how the operator is applied, the result is 
('{0} {0}' -f 1)+[System.String] (2,2)  # [System.String] $somearray is ($somearray -join ' ')

And speaking of -join, the precedence goes

unary -join
,
binary -join

so

-join 1,2 is (-join 1),2 = ('1',2) # ([String],[Int32])
-join (1,2) = '12'
1,2 -join '' is (1,2) -join '' = '12'

BTW, just to be technically precise, the OP is using an array of arrays, not a two dimensional array, which is why the element access syntax was wrong. If the OP had actually created a two dimensional array (as in $spelbordd = new-object 'Boolean[,]' 10,10) then the element access syntax would have been correct.